# i can't get my JsonOject after calling requestData() function

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get a JsonObject from a local server,this is my object:

```
[
   {
      "id":2,
      "latitude":34.042542,
      "longitude":-4.997182,
      "title":"zone1",
      "icone":"http://192.168.1.50/Heloo/images/icone.png"
   }
]
```

i want to set 3 variables (**JsonLat** as double by latitude/ **JsonLong** as double by longitude / **JsonName** as string by title ) but after executing my application i can't get this value .

- My **requestData(url)** is in **onCreate()** just after **setContentView()**.
- this is my HttpManager class :

  ```
      import java.io.BufferedReader;
      import java.io.IOException;
      import java.io.InputStreamReader;
      import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
      import java.net.URL;


  public class HttpManager {

  public static String getData(String uri) {

  BufferedReader reader = null;

  try {
      URL url = new URL(uri);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          sb.append(line + "\n");
      }

      return sb.toString();

  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
  } finally {
      if (reader != null) {
          try {
              reader.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              return null;
          }
      }
  }

  }

  }
  ```
- this is my requestData() definition and MyTask class :

  ```
  public void requestData(String uri) {
  MyTask task = new MyTask();
  task.execute(uri);
  }

  public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  //          updateDisplay("Starting task");

      //tasks.add(this);
  }

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

      String content = HttpManager.getData(params[0]);
      return content;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      try {

             JSONArray cast = new JSONArray(result);
               for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
              JSONObject Marker = new JSONObject(cast.get(i).toString());
              JsonLat = Marker.getDouble("latitude");
              Jsonlong = Marker.getDouble("longitude");
              JsonName = Marker.getString("title");
          }

      } catch (JSONException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

  }
  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
  //          updateDisplay(values[0]);
  }

  }
  ```

  **EDIT** : I tried to show the values with the log.v inside the try{} , i can see my values , but when i tried to use the value outside the try {} it doesn't work , also when i try to apply a function with JsonLat ,Jsonlng , JsonName as parameters inside the try{} it doesn't work as well it seems that there is a probleme with try{} or i don't know !!!!!

Comment: post your logcat what error you are getting??

Comment: nothing , my app works but my 3 variables still has 0 and null  as value

Answer (score 1):

You are getting JSONArray from server ..You have to parse JsonArray

```
JSONArray cast // your jsonarray object 
for (int i=0; i<cast.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject  Marker = new JSONObject(cast.get(i));
        JsonLat = Marker.getDouble("latitude");
        Jsonlong = Marker.getDouble("longitude");
        JsonName = Marker.getString("title");
}
```

Comment: your suggestion should work for me , but when i try to initialize my marker by cast.get(i) i get can't resolve constructor 'JSONObject(java.lang.Object) ' should i Cast parameter to java.lang.string ??

Comment: @IsmailiAlaouismail print cast.get(i) value

Comment: try to cast it in string

Comment: i cast it in string :  still null values and i got this : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String   !!! i tried this : cast.get(i).toString() , doesn't work as well :/

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works when I try with another random JSON data. I think your problem is with `getDouble()` methods. You can just get them all as strings with `getString()` method. Then you can make conversion in Java.

Comment: Yes. Are you sure the data is correct? Because I tried your code with some other JSON data and all worked well. And in case of fail, logcat must show some JSONException, can you be missing that?

Comment: This my logcat message on JSONException:Value [{"id":2,"title":"zone1","longitude":-4.997182,"latitude":34.042542,"icone":"http:\/\/192.168.1.50\/Heloo\/images\/icone.png"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject .

Comment: this is my probleme i think , i have a JSONArray not a JSONObject : i found this detail on net :
[....] is an array e.g. [ "android" , "httpclient" , "internet" ]
{….} is an object e.g. { tags:[...] , categories:[...] , url:”…” , title:”…” }